# How to make this expression?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

How to code this expression in WolframAlpha. I am interested in how to code the second sum, because it contains a boolean expression:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}{\sum_{j>n}}{x_{i}x_{j}}$$

Comment: You can sometimes use a subset of Mathematica notation in WolframAlpha. It seems to understand `Sum[Sum[i j,{j,n+1,Infinity}],{i,1,100}]` but it does not understand subscripts or free variable names.

Comment: The following seems to work: `sum i * j, i from n+1 to 100, j from 1 to 100`

Comment: Use indexed variables rather than subscripts: `sum x[i]*x[j], i from 1 to 100, j from n+1 to 100`